# Reading a text file in drjava and giving the output similar to an adjacency list. What are my mistakes?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, nodes, drjava

My input file has the following information: first digit is number of nodes, next is number of edges and the following ones are the edges.

5

6

1,2

2,4

3,5

1,2

2,4

3,5

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class JavaApplication1 {
  public static void main(String\[\] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();  
    // TODO code application logic here.
    File f = new File("D:\\Documents\\Study\\Spring '18\\CSE221\\FSI\\CSE221\\Labs\\Lab01\\AdjacencyList\\input.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    String line = s.nextLine();
    int noOfNode = Integer.parseInt(line);
    line = s.nextLine();
    int noOfEdge = Integer.parseInt(line);
    while(s.hasNext()){
      System.out.println("While visited");
      line = s.nextLine();
      for(int i = 0; line != null; i++, line = s.nextLine()){
        System.out.println("i For visited " + i + " time");
        String \[\] splitA = line.split(",");
        ArrayList<Integer> node= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(node);
        for(int j = 0; line == s.nextLine();j++){
          System.out.println("j For visited " + j + " time");  
          System.out.print(list.get(i).add(Integer.parseInt(splitA\[j\])) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you remove the `drjava` tag? This is a pure Java issue, not related to the IDE.

Comment: I only see input and code. What's the problem you're facing? What's the expected result, what do you get instead? Where does the error occur?